# How to avoid nogoriki to_html encode Chinese characters to numbers?

Tags: ruby

I have a Nogoriki Element contains Chinese words:

```
pry(main)> el
=> #(Element:0x3ff979d93e44 {
  name = "p",
  attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3ff979b8259c { name = "class", value = "h1" })],
  children = [ #(Text "長阿含經序")]
  })
```

it's ok if I am using `to_str` method:

```
pry(main)> el.to_str
=> "長阿含經序"
```

But not work with `to_html`:

```
pry(main)> el.to_html
=> "<p class=\"h1\">&#38263;&#38463;&#21547;&#32147;&#24207;</p>\n"
```

Above string contains weird numbers, I expect it to be:

```
pry(main)> el.to_html
=> "<p class=\"h1\">長阿含經序</p>\n"
```